# Module Dependencies vs Local Dependencies vs Remote Dependencies

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have gone through [Building Your Project with Gradle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html) a couple of times but never understood when to use local dependencies and when not to use remote dependencies when building android application

Answer (score 0):

The choice of which of those three you use isn't really a preference- the primary determining factor in choosing which of the three to use is how the library is provided to you.

If the library you want to use is only provided as a JAR file, then it is a **local dependency**. This just refers to the collection of compiled libraries included with your project.

If the library is provided as raw, uncompiled code, then it will need to be a **module dependency**. These are all of the libraries that Gradle needs to compile before building your main application module.

If the author of the library is kind enough to upload the library to a repository such as Maven Central or jCenter, then you should use that as a **remote dependency**. This means that Gradle will download the dependency from that repository before building (if it isn't already cached locally).

You should always prefer remote dependencies when possible. If you use a remote dependency it is trivial to update your libraries- all you need to do is update the version number in your build.gradle's dependency section and Gradle will automatically fetch that version. Remote dependencies eliminate the need to manually download updates.